# boundingRectWithSize returning wrong height

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wrote the following method to calculate the height of an *NSAttributedString* with given width:

```
- (CGFloat)findHeightForText:(NSString *)text havingWidth:(CGFloat)widthValue {
    CGFloat height = 0.0;
    if (text) {
        CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(widthValue, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin| NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14 weight:UIFontWeightRegular] } context:nil];
        height = ceil(frame.size.height);
    }
    return height;
}
```

Apart from the colour, the attributed string of the label has only a font attribute:

`NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14 weight:UIFontWeightRegular]`

The problem is that occasionally it returns an incorrect value. E.g. I see that the text is laid out in three lines, however the height value that I get is for two lines. Similarly, sometimes it returns the height value for two lines, whereas the text can be laid out using a single line.

I'm not passing the paragraph style, because *NSLineBreakByWordWrapping* is the default value.

I've read the similar threads, but none of them gave me the solution. What am I missing?

Comment: How is the text actually being drawn?